# How to remove Google Analytics React firing event from the console?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I implemented react-ga to my project and I set debug option to false:

```js
ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXX-XXX', {
    debug: false
});
```

And still, each time GA tracks an event that was firing, it shows it in the console:

[image: google analytics console log]

How can I remove these updates?